# Defining constants in C#

Tags: c#, c++, constants

I'm C/C++ to C# developer.

I need to do something like below,

```
#define LEN 20
int data[LEN];
```

Since C# doesn't support `#define`, many forums suggests to declare a `const` variable. A `const` variable might help me for below, but not for above.

```
for (int a = 0; a < LEN; a++)
{
    x += data[LEN - a - 1];
}
```

So, how do I use the constant for array declarations as well?

Comment: Even in C++ you shouldn't use preprocessor macros to define constants...

Comment: What do you mean by "not for above"? `int x = data[LEN];` doesn't declare an array-type variable, nor does it create an array - that has nothing to do with constants, it's just incorrect syntax. You could use `int[] data = new int[LEN];`...

Comment: 1) "_how do I use the constant for array declarations as well?_" The thing is.. The array size doesn't _have_ to be constant in C#, for the same reason as you don't need to pass constant value to `new[LEN]` in C++. There are no arrays with automatic storage duration, as there is in C++. 2) `#define` doesn't create a constant. It is merely a textual replacement, which uses find-and-replace to replace every occurence of `LEN` to `20`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt can you please share me why we shouldn't do so?

Comment: @JonSkeet "above" meaning declaring an array. The statement `int x = data[LEN];` is corrected now.

Comment: I'm still very confused about what you're having a problem with. As I've said, if you want to create an array with `LEN` elements, you use `int[] data = new int[LEN];`. That has nothing to do with `LEN` being a constant.

Comment: Just search for "C++ macros are evil", you'll have plenty stuff to read.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should use it for the instantiation of the array:

```
const int LEN = 20;
int[] data = new int[LEN];
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. What is `LEN`?

Comment: Well I assumed that it was clear, since the issue was related to declaration syntax, I modified my answer to be more clear ^^

Answer (score 1):

C# lets you create constants of several built-in types [using `const` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const).

> Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference.

Here is a small example:

```
public class Demo {

    public const int Length = 20;

    public void Main(string[] args) {
        var data = new int[Length];
        for (var i = 0 ; i != Length ; i++) {
            data[i] = 2*i + 3;
        }
    }

}
```

**Note:** [C# naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) suggest avoiding all-caps naming.

Comment: Thanks for naming guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
static readonly int LEN = 20;

static void Main(string[] args)
{    
   int[] data = new int[LEN];
   for (int a = 0; a < LEN; a++)
   {
        int x = data[LEN];
   }
 }
```

please note that that date array will be default initialized to 0.

also, you will get `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` for  `int x = data[LEN];` because you are asking for the 20th index and there is no such index in the array

Comment: he said he's a c++ developer but still doesn't know that arrays are zero based indexing... strange

Comment: @sLowDowN Thank you nitpicker. Question is updated to satisfy you.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use constants to declare an array length. Also, there are many data structures in C# that allow you to have a dynamic size array/list/dictionary...